# Spotify Apps still available?

Tags: spotify, spotify-app

Does Spotify sill supports in-app Apps? I saw a couple of them the other but cannot find any examples/docs today?

Did Spotify really stopped apps that run inside the Spotify App?

Answer (score 2):

> Please note: Future releases of the Spotify Desktop client will no
>   longer feature an App Finder tab and will no longer support the
>   presentation of Spotify Apps, therefore this API has been
>   discontinued.

https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/